# Shopify Staff account read only permission

Tags: shopify

In shopify store how to create the staff account with app read only permission (i.e.,) the staff can access the app but he can't able to uninstall/modify the app.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a Staff account with only Read Only permissions. If you have given access user to Apps then the user can install/modify/uninstall any of the apps. However, only the owner can approve a charge i.e. payment for any of the app. Documentation for Shopify permissions - [Link](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/your-account/staff-accounts/staff-permissions)